# getting directories and subdirectories using python OS and outputting csv file

Tags: python, operating-system

I want to write Python code to create a CSV file based on getting information from a directory and subdirectories only if the subdirectory contains moo.

```
.
├── a.txt
├── b.txt
├── foo
│   └── w.txt
│   └── a.txt
└── moo
    └── cool.csv
    └── bad.csv
    └── more
        └── wow.csv
```

Expected Pandas dataframe:

```
FilePath    
S:\Test\moo\cool.csv
S:\Test\moo\bad.csv
S:\Test\moo\cool.csv
S:\Test\moo\more\wow.csv
```

How can I do this in python?

So far I gave the following code but not sure how to complete:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

root = 'S:\Test'
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
      print(path)
```

Comment: Instead of printing the path, write it to the CSV file.

Comment: Use a raw string for pathnames containing backslash: `r'S:\Test'`

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import csv

# Set the base directory
base_dir = 'S:\\Test'

# Initialize an empty list to store the file paths
file_paths = []

# Iterate through the directories and subdirectories
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_dir):
    # Iterate through the files
    for file in files:
        # Get the full path of the file
        file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
        # Add the file path to the list
        file_paths.append(file_path)

# Open a CSV file for writing
with open('file_paths.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    # Create a CSV writer
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    # Write the file paths to the CSV file
    writer.writerows([[file_path] for file_path in file_paths])
```

This code will iterate through the directories and subdirectories of the base directory, collect the file paths in a list, and then write the list to a CSV file called file_paths.csv.

If you want to use the pandas module to create a dataframe from the file paths, you can do so by using the following code after writing the file paths to the CSV file:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the CSV file into a dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('file_paths.csv', header=None, names=['FilePath'])
```

Comment: This is great. Is there a way to filter to where the next inner folder = 'moo'? That way I only get file paths for every coming after S:\Test\moo\ would show.

Comment: Yes, you can modify the code to filter the file paths based on the next inner folder being "moo". Here's one way you could do this: